# I want to get the id when I click a RecyclerView item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

when clicked the item of recycleview.i want to get the ID of the item of  and use them in another Service in Main activity recycleview is working fine just want get id from adapter and use it to main activity  here is my code  of adapter and main Activity class in which show the

```
    private void loadrent() {
    l.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    shimmerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    shimmerLayout.startShimmerAnimation();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, 
                                         URLs.user_rent_data_guest,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        Integer a;
                        shimmerLayout.stopShimmerAnimation();
                        shimmerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //converting the string to json array object
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray array =jsonResponse.getJSONArray("data");
                       // JSONArray arrays =jsonResponse.getJSONArray("0");
                        //traversing through all the object
                        if(array != null && array.length() > 0 ) {
                            l.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                //getting product object from json array
                                JSONObject product =array.getJSONObject(i);
                      //JSONObject products =arrays.getJSONObject(i);
                                //adding the product to product lists
                                productList.add(new Rent(
                                        product.getInt("id"),
                                        product.getString("tags"),
                                        product.getString("address"),
                                        product.getString("details"),
                                        product.getString("amount"),
                                        product.getString("cover_image"),
                                        product.getString("location"),
                                        product.getString("contact"),
                                        product.getString("status"),
                                        product.getString("no_of_bedrooms"),
                                        product.getString("no_of_bathrooms"),
                                        product.getString("property_floor"),
                                        product.getString("created_at"),
                                        product.getString("property_name")
                                ));
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            shimmerLayout.stopShimmerAnimation();
                            shimmerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                        //creating adapter object and setting it to recyclerview
                        adapter = new rentgestAdapter(SubmitPost.this,productList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    shimmerLayout.stopShimmerAnimation();
                    shimmerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

    //adding our stringrequest to queue
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
}



public class rentgestAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<rentgestAdapter.rentgestAdapterholder> {


private Context mCtx;
private List<Rent> productList;
private String time,s;
Date currentTimes;
Integer soft;
Date date1,date2;
Date today;

public rentgestAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Rent> productList) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.productList = productList;
}

@Override
public rentgestAdapterholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);
    return new rentgestAdapterholder(view);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(rentgestAdapterholder holder, int position) {
    final Rent product = productList.get(position);


    //loading the image
    //loading the image

    holder.lsItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

     Integer s=product.getId();


        }
    });
    AssetManager am = mCtx.getApplicationContext().getAssets();
    Typeface face= Typeface.createFromAsset(am,"fonts/nobellights.ttf");
    Typeface face1= Typeface.createFromAsset(am,"fonts/NobelBold.ttf");
    holder.textViewamunt.setTypeface(face1);
    holder.name.setTypeface(face);
    holder.textViewtag.setTypeface(face);
    holder.bed.setTypeface(face);
    holder.bath.setTypeface(face);
    holder.floor.setTypeface(face);
    holder.textViewaddress.setTypeface(face);
    holder.textViewdetail.setTypeface(face);


    holder.textViewamunt.setText(String.valueOf(product.getPrice())+" PKR");
    holder.name.setText(product.getname());
    holder.textViewaddress.setText(String.valueOf(product.get_address()));
   // holder.textViewtag.setText(String.valueOf(product.get_sale_tag()));
    if(product.get_sale_tag().equals(""))
    {
        holder.textViewtag.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        holder.textViewtag.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.textViewtag.setText(String.valueOf(product.get_sale_tag()));
    }
    holder.textViewdetail.setText(String.valueOf(product.getdetails()));
    if(product.getbed().equals(""))
    {
        holder.bed.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
    else{
        holder.bed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.bed.setText(String.valueOf(product.getbed())+" Bed");

    }
    if(product.getBath().equals(""))
    {
        holder.bath.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
    else{
        holder.bath.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.bath.setText(String.valueOf(product.getBath())+" Bath");

    }
    if(product.getFloor().equals(""))
    {
        holder.floor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
    else{
        holder.floor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.floor.setText(String.valueOf(product.getFloor())+" Floor");

    }
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd hh:mm:ss");
    try {
        DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd hh:mm:ss");
        dateFormatter.setLenient(false);
        today = new Date();
        s = dateFormatter.format(today);
        date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(product.getcreated_at());
        date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(s);
        printDifference(date1, date2);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    holder.t.setText(String.valueOf(time));
    holder.shineButton.setOnCheckStateChangeListener(new ShineButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(View view, boolean checked) {
            Log.e("ssssss", "click " + checked);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productList.size();
}
public String printDifference(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    //milliseconds
    long different = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

    System.out.println("startDate : " + startDate);
    System.out.println("endDate : "+ endDate);


    long secondsInMilli = 1000;
    long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
    long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
    long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

    long elapsedDays = different / daysInMilli;
    different = different % daysInMilli;

    long elapsedHours = different / hoursInMilli;
    different = different % hoursInMilli;

    long elapsedMinutes = different / minutesInMilli;
    different = different % minutesInMilli;

    long elapsedSeconds = different / secondsInMilli;

    System.out.printf(
            "%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds%n",
            elapsedDays, elapsedHours, elapsedMinutes, elapsedSeconds);
    time= elapsedDays+" Days "+" "+elapsedHours+" Hours  "+" "+elapsedMinutes+" Minutes";
    return time;
}

class rentgestAdapterholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   ShineButton shineButton ;

    TextView textViewamunt, textViewdetail, textViewaddress, textViewtag,bed,bath,floor,t,name;
    ImageView imageView;
    public android.support.v7.widget.CardView lsItem;



    public rentgestAdapterholder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        shineButton= (ShineButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.po_image2);
        textViewamunt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pkramount);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        textViewdetail =  (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.detail);
        t =  (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.t);
        bed = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bed);
        bath = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bath);
        floor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.floor);
        textViewtag = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tag);
        textViewaddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.address);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.simage);
        lsItem = (android.support.v7.widget.CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lsItem);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use an interface to pass the id back to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

**First:** You could create a interface for providing callback listener:

```
interface UpdateActivityListener {
    void itemClicked(int id);
}
```

**Second:** Your adapter should keep listener, but activity should implements:

```
public rentgestAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Rent> productList, UpdateActivityListener listener) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.productList = productList;
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

**Third:**  Set to your view default `setOnClickListener` and call your listener with pass id.

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // holder.getAdapterPosition() returns click item position
        listener.itemClicked(holder.getAdapterPosition());
    }
});
```

Comment: how can i get id in Activity